# date bash script works under RHEL but not ubuntu

Tags: bash

the script from [How to keep: daily backups for a week, weekly for a month, monthly for a year, and yearly after that](https://serverfault.com/questions/575163/how-to-keep-daily-backups-for-a-week-weekly-for-a-month-monthly-for-a-year-a)
works under RHEL7 but reports errors when used on two separate ubuntu machines

I do not find what could be wrong with it besides it has loops within loops and some expressions are not quoted

```
keepdates () 
{ 
    for i in {0..7};
    do
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++));
    done;
    for i in {0..4};
    do
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++));
    done;
    for i in {0..12};
    do
        DW=$(($(date +%-W)-$(date -d $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y-%m-01) +%-W)));
        for ((AY=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ ))
        do
            ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)));
        done;
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++));
    done;
    for i in {0..5};
    do
        DW=$(date +%-W);
        for ((AY=$(($(date +%Y)-i)); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ ))
        do
            ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)));
        done;
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++));
    done;
    echo ${!keep[@]}
}
```

The error is:

```
-bash: ./test.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: ./test.sh: line 18: `        done;'
```

any idea?

## added output under RHEL7

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.

$ keepdates; # my custom function but a bash script would do the same
20130106 20140105 20150104 20160103 20170101 20170205 20170305 20170402 20170507 20170604 20170702 20170806 20170903 20171001 20171105 20171203 20171224 20171231 20180107 20180114 20180117 20180118 20180119 20180120 20180121 20180122 20180123 20180124
```

Comment: Your script is full of unnecessary semicolons. Try removing these.

Comment: Do a `set -x` before launching the command it will display each line before executing it. Since the script depends heavily on the `date` command it may work differently. Are the locales the same also?

Comment: This looks like a function. Where is the script that call this function (`test.sh)` ? 'cause line 18 seems to have nothing to do with this function.

Comment: OK it is a function as shown but that does not change the problem, it should print an array of dates in the form 20180101 which it does on rhel but fails to do with the exact same code on ubuntu. Please just ignore the function name and braces. I tried removing semicolons and it did not improve. Both have bash 3 and gnutils of slightly different versions. Could it be that ubuntu bash does not expand the internal date calls correctly? I tried adding "" around some but it rapidely led to syntax issues.

Comment: You never specified the exact shell you are using.  Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian, which tends to use dash for some things instead of bash.  Also, if you are really desperate, have you considered simply encoding the `date` command as a variable, i.e. `DATECMD=/usr/bin/date` and then reference it as `$DATECMD` in your script?

Comment: In general, a good StackOverflow question should be narrowed to a single, specific problem -- not "why doesn't my script work?", but "why does <this command> do X instead of Y when given a variable with value Z?". That *is* possible if using `set -x` to log what each line of your script does -- you can track down the first place it does something other than what you expect by that line-by-line trace of execution (particularly if setting `PS4=':$LINENO+'` to log each line number next to that line's execution). See the Help Center on building a [mcve]; note **Minimal**.

Comment: Dear professors, thanks for your critical comments. The issue was not related to the semicolons but to the nested date calls. Mario, below, found the problem and made comments which helped me understand the real problem. I personally prefer answers with a solution rather than criticisms that just confirm my student status which is no news to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I have no fedora but openSUSE 42.3 with GNU bash, Version 4.3.42(1)-release.)

The unnecessary semicolons have already been mentioned above. You call the date command with a fix result in your loops.

I wrote sequencies with $(seq from to) but that's just cosmetics, the {1..3} notation works too, I did not know that before.

The main problem is the nested date call in line 13 and the date call within the double expression evaluation in line 23 of your original post.

I have solved that by pulling out the fixed variables motm (MiddleOfTheMonth) and EY (EndYear).

**For Line 13:** 
in this for condition `$(date +%Y-%m-15)` is fixed, why should the value be recalculated every time, same for `$(date +%Y)`, try this line alone:

```
i=5; for ((AY=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do echo $AY; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

and with the `$mdtm`:

```
motm="2018-01-15"; i=5; for ((AY=$(date -d "$motm -$i month" +%Y); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do echo $AY; done
2017
```

**For Line 23** you can observe the for condition:

```
i=2; for ((AY=$(($(date +%Y)-i));AY<2018;AY++));do echo $AY; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

and

```
i=2; for ((AY=$((2018-i));AY<2018;AY++));do echo $AY; done
2016
2017
```

I do not know what goes wrong in the bash. I can only tell you how to write it down so it works.

This one produce the same on openSUSE and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

```
#!/bin/bash
keepdates () 
{
    local -a keep
    for i in $(seq 0 7)
    do
        (( keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++ ))
    done
    for i in $(seq 0 4)
    do
        (( keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++ ))
    done
    motm=$(date +%Y-%m-15)
    for i in $(seq 0 12)
    do
        DW=$(( $(date +%-W)-$(date -d $(date -d "$motm -$i month" +%Y-%m-01) +%-W) ))

        for  (( AY=$(date -d "$motm -$i month" +%Y);  $AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ ))
        do
            (( DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W) ))
        done
        (( keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++ ))
    done
    for i in $(seq 0 5)
    do
        DW=$(date +%-W)
        EY=$(date +%Y)
        for (( AY=$(( EY-i )); $AY < $EY; AY++ ))
        do
            (( DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W) ))
        done
        (( keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++ ))
    done
    echo ${!keep[@]}
}
keepdates
```

Comment: Dear Mario,Your code works, THANK you very much. I now ned to understand what you did as I really want to know. defining the array object was also advised by [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) but did not help in my attempts

Comment: really appreciate your time, Best